OCFS2 + ISCSI - Mounting error "Heartbeat mode is invalid while trying to join the group"
An OCFS2 cluster with two nodes is attempting to work with storage that has two block devices. These devices are shared via iSCSI and are visible on both nodes. Smaller disk (230 gb) utilized for heartbeat, bigger (5.5 tb)- for storage. However, if I try to mount the device or the mpath of the device, I receive an error:
[root@ovm02 ~]# mount -t ocfs2 /dev/mapper/36001405efce93b538764a0f934a7f78c /OVS/Repositories
mount.ocfs2: Heartbeat mode is invalid while trying to join the group

Attempt to mount /dev/sdd — returning same result.
Nodes statuses are absolutely ok
[root@ovm02 ~]# service o2cb status
Driver for "configfs": Loaded
Filesystem "configfs": Mounted
Stack glue driver: Loaded
Stack plugin "o2cb": Loaded
Driver for "ocfs2_dlmfs": Loaded
Filesystem "ocfs2_dlmfs": Mounted
Checking O2CB cluster "95a828f93f00bd60": Online
  Heartbeat dead threshold: 61
  Network idle timeout: 60000
  Network keepalive delay: 2000
  Network reconnect delay: 2000
  Heartbeat mode: Global
Checking O2CB heartbeat: Active
  1E3ADD52196E4AF9B5565F4A9D9F93A4 /dev/dm-1
Nodes in O2CB cluster: 0 1 
Debug file system at /sys/kernel/debug: mounted

OCFS2/OS/KERNEL version
filename:       /lib/modules/3.8.13-26.4.2.el6uek.x86_64/kernel/fs/ocfs2/ocfs2.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Oracle
version:        1.8.0
description:    OCFS2 1.8.0
srcversion:     54320504732C88B1365858A
depends:        jbd2,ocfs2_stackglue,ocfs2_nodemanager
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.8.13-26.4.2.el6uek.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions 

kernel-uek-firmware-3.8.13-26.4.2.el6uek.noarch
kernel-uek-3.8.13-26.4.2.el6uek.x86_64

ocfs2-tools-1.8.6-11.el6.x86_64
ocfs2-tools-devel-1.8.6-11.el6.x86_64

I don't see any visible problems in the dmesg output as well.
But not reboot, nor remaking filesystem with any parameters did't make affect.
Google hasn't yielded any similair results.
I'll be appreciate for any ideas.
